# query select multiple table

Tags: mysql, join, select

Hí,

I need to select all **COMISSIONARIO** and all **FATURA's** them. But I have no idea how do it. I tried one query as the image below but it not working. It showing all **FATURA** but just one **COMISSIONARIO** by **FATURA**

[Query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XwBFx.png)

[Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AFgvR.png)

Comment: Please edit your existing question and please paste your query directly in the question.  Once posted in, highlight the query and do Ctrl+K to have it formatted as code for readability vs just a wrapping paragraph.  Best to have here than an image that could get hosed.

Answer (score -1):

I'm reversing your query a bit starting with your final WHERE clause based on some status. Since the Comissionario table is WHERE "Required" on the status, I moved that into the second position of the query.  Then worked the rest of the tables back to the fatura table.

```
select
        f.valor valor_fatura,
        f.numero numero,
        f.id_cliente,
        des.nome despachante,
        v.nome vendedor,
        tipo.tipo tipo_commisionado,
        u.unidade unidade_cobranca,
        com.valor_comissao taxa,
        if( u.unidade = 'moeda',
                com.valor_comissao,
                FORMAT(( ( com.valor_comissao * f.valor ) / 100 ), 2 )
            ) valor_comissao,
        f.created_at,
        f.updated_at,
        f.created_by,
        f.updated_by
    from
        -- start with all commisionario status (alias cs)
        ComissionarioStatus cs
            -- now on to comissionario (alias com) that match key status
            JOIN comissionario com
                on cs.id_comissionariostatus = com.id_comissionariostatus
                -- now the tipo and unicob with shorter alias
                left join ComissionarioTipo tipo
                    on com.id_comissionariotipo = tipo.id_comissionariotipo
                left join Unicob u
                    on com.id_unicob = u.id_unicob
                -- now getting the individual
                join Individuo des
                    on com.id_comissionado = des.id_individuo
                    join captacao cap
                        on des.id_individuo = cap.id_despachante
                        left join proposta p
                            on cap.id_proposta = p.id_proposta
                            left join Individuo v
                                on p.id_vendedor = v.id_individuo
                        join fatura f
                            on cap.id_captacao = f.id_captacao 
    where
        -- where the one status you want
        cs.status = 'ativo'
```

This was just a first start, but if you look at your query, you are trying to find Fatura records associated with Comissionario records, so to get each of these, you need a regular JOIN to pull the records together.

Also, if you look at the indentation level of tables, you can see how I stepped from one table to the next and how the ID key from the left-side table (first table) matches the ID on the right-side table (second table joining TO).  I believe seeing how A -> B -> C, you are first guaranteeing the relationships between the tables.  Optional would be left-join as you originally had on some.  But since your where clause was based on a specific status, that forces any left-join getting to the comissionario table to a JOIN.  So now, to get from that back to fatura, each subsequent associated also needed to be a JOIN vs left join.

Now, having said all that, lets try to clarify what you are looking for in your final output.  Your diagram showed many tables and relationships, but take a step back. What are your REQUIRED parts... Something from both the Comissionario table AND Fatura table?  If so, please provide the SHORTEST LINK of relationship tables that get from one to the other.  These will all be direct JOIN conditions.  Start your query with that.  Once you get THAT resolved, now start to tack on the other elements with left-joins where applicable.  Example, I would then add your ComissionarioStatus table with the specific status next.

As you gradually add each additional table with either JOIN or LEFT JOIN, find out which one breaks the result set you are expecting and ask yourself why... Should it be a LEFT JOIN? or not.

using Shorter, yet somewhat meaningful aliases to the tables can help too.